# Resumes/Continues

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

The police officer keeps firing at the man. Suddenly his gun runs out of bullets. He reaches into his bag, takes out another gun and resumes/continues firing at the man.

Is "resumes" more fitting than "continues" here because he stopped shooting when he ran out of bullets?

Comment: His gun runs out of **bullets** (plural).

Comment: Have you compared the meanings of "resume" and "continue" in a dictionary?

Comment: I have, but I'm still not sure. Especially about "continue".

Comment: To resume is to continue after an interval of time; you can use either.

Answer (score 1):

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/):

[Continue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/continue):

> to start to do something again after a pause

[Resume](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resume):

> If an activity resumes, or if you resume it, it starts again after a pause:

They both mean to start again after a pause, so they can be used interchangeably. However, **continue** is [used more frequently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resume%20doing%2Ccontinue%20doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresume%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinue%20doing%3B%2Cc0) in our lives.